# About facebook unity plugin 4.3.3, how to add it in current project?

Tags: facebook, plugins, unity-game-engine

I upgrade facebook unity plugin from version 4.2.4 to 4.3.3 yesterday.

For the old version, I just add the jar file in project/plugin/Android and add some specific code to use it.

As for the new version, it just give me a whole facebook android project, what am I supposed to do with it?

1. Compile it to an jar and use it like before?
2. Export my project and also with FB project then package it in Eclipse?(which is super waste of time everytime)

In fact I tried both:

1 . this is not works anymore, result in some resource id errors.

2 . I did make out a package, but it can not login like it works before in 4.2.4.

Does anyone meet same problem like I did?

I really think A sdk should not give whole prject out, because as a running project, there is too much sdk to add in, we dont have to much time to deal with each plugin everytime. A big company like facebook should make things easier.

BTW: the instructions on Facebook page is old, I could not get useful information from them.

Comment: Luck the old 4.2.4 version still works in the old way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to just "Build and Run" with the new 4.3.3 version (if you imported the package and left the structure as is.  Be sure to clear out the old Facebook SDK before you import this one.)  Unity would automatically compile it in with your project.

To answer your questions on why we did this:

1. The reason why it got switch away from a jar is that in the older version when it was compiled to the jar, it meant the R class had hard-coded resource ids at compile time (of the jar).  Unfortunately, when other plugins were introduced into a project, it reorders the resource ids but doesn't adjust the R class within the jar.  This would break integration and make integrating Facebook with the other android plugins useless.
2. The source of the android files were packaged along with it because several developers requested more ways to edit the code to their needs.  There's several android plugins for Unity out there and while we do our best to make sure our Unity SDK plays nice with them, there can be cases were a developer would like extra control on how they merge together.

With that said, since you upgraded your project from 4.2.4 to 4.3.3, did you follow the changelog here: https://developers.facebook.com/unity/change-log-4.x/#131013?

Basically what happened was that since importing a package doesn't let us delete old files, there was no way to clean up projects that used the jar method.  Keeping them both in the project breaks the android build.  This is only a one time migration that should happen again.